# Rails AssetNotPrecompiledError even though the assets are being precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm new to both Ruby and Rails, I've been mulling over this for days and haven't found a solution. My project works fine on my development environment, but it won't on my alpha or production environments.

I have the following stylesheets on my app/assets/stylesheets folder:

```
app
--> assets
  --> stylesheets
    --> modules
      --> _header.css.scss
      --> _footer.css.scss
    --> home.css.scss
    --> user.css.scss
    --> help.css.scss
```

When I try using my alpha environment (that is, by running `rails s --environment=alpha`) I get this error:

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Home#index
Showing /app/views/home/index.haml where line #1 raised:
home.css isn't precompiled
```

I'm adding that stylesheet to my view by using `stylesheet_link_tag('home')`.

My `alpha.rb` file has this:

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.precompile += %w( help.css home.css users.css )
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.debug = false
```

I am running the precompile task (that is, `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=alpha`). The task seems to be working properly. This is the output:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=alpha --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=alpha RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Invoke rails_admin:disable_initializer (first_time)
** Execute rails_admin:disable_initializer
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
```

My files do end up in `/public/assets/`, and the `/public/assets/manifest.yml` is being created and has my files listed in it:

```
application.css: application.css
help.css: help.css
home.css: home.css
users.css: users.css
```

If I try to access the server (by going to `http://localhost:3000`) I get the previously mentioned `AssetNotPrecompiledError` error for `home.css`; however, `http://localhost:3000/assets/home.css` does return the stylesheet.

AFAIK this error is being generated because Rails doesn't know where `home.css` is located; however, it is listed on the `manifest.yml`, where I think it's supposed to look for it.

If you need any more information I'll be happy to provide it. This is driving me nuts!

-- EDIT --

As per Qumara SixOneTour's request, here is my application.css.scss:

```
@import 'modules/header';
@import 'modules/footer';

body {
    background: $bgColor asset-url('bgFull.jpg', image) repeat-x center top;
}

div.main {
    padding: 35px 30px;
    background: $whitweColor;
    margin-top: -3px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    @include border-bottom-left-radius(5px);
    @include border-bottom-right-radius(5px);

    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
        background: $bgColor asset-url('bg.png', image) repeat-x;
    }
}
```

Basically, I don't use a manifest, but instead load separate css files in every view.

Comment: Could you post `application.css` file ?

Comment: I added it to the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having exactly the same problem with a new Rails 3.1.11 app, and i even get the AssetNotPrecompiledError for images (that are in /app/assets/images and precompile over to /public/assets).

Comment: Sorry @ilasno, I never did... stuff like this made me stop using Rails. I'm much more productive now with Node.js and Express.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to stick to the defaults concerning the manifest files . They are meant to be management points of the asset-pipeline . In your case there are a couple things to do :

- move any `css` definitions from `application.css` to a separate css file in `app/assets/stylesheets`
- include your parts in a "manifest" style - it is a strange one , you can tell the rows are commented , but they are not. Like this :

  ```
  *= require_self  
  *= require jquery 
  *= require jquery_ujs
  *= require_tree .
  ```
- if you are extending `assets/stylesheets` with new directories , just like you are trying to do , it is better to mention this in `application.rb` like this :

  ```
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "styleshhets", "modules")
  ```

One last suggestion : remove your `public/assets` in development environment . It makes the things uselessly complicated . Just rely on `app/assets`.

Comment: I don't want to use the application.css as a manifest, because some CSS rules will conflict with each other if they are all loaded. I'd very much rather load a separate CSS/JS file per HTML document; I'm sure Rails has a way to do this, since there is a way to add assets to config.assets.precompile. The assets are being precompiled AFAIK, it's just that rails doesn't know about them. I've tried setting config.assets.manifest manually, but no dice :(

Comment: Is it OK if you separate your `.js` (or `.css`) files  depending on controller they are related to?

Comment: For now I think it'll do, but I'd probably need something more granular, like a different js or css file per view.

Answer (score -2):

In your `alpha.rb` set `config.assets.compile` to `true` to pre-compile assets

Comment: This is not viable performance-wise. Too much unnecessary overhead to load a couple of static css & js files.